# What is the best way to create a tab view within a ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, swift4

I'm trying to create a design where a section of the ViewController has three buttons that show different content depending on what button is selected. Basically UITabBarController but within a viewcontroller

[image: Design]

Basically the deer, fish and the bird icons will be buttons, showing different content in an imageView below. Is there a built in function in Xcode that you recommend for this? Or should I create three buttons, showing/hiding the relevant UIViews? What is the most efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Your image isn't showing up but could a Segmented Control be what you are after?
[image]

Hook its Value Changed up to an action in your View Controller and respond to which item is selected by showing/hiding different views for example:

```
@IBAction func controlChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let segmentedControl = sender as? UISegmentedControl else { return }

    let activeViewIndex = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
    // Show the view based on activeViewIndex here
}
```

Comment: SegmentController seem to be what I am looking for. However in the Xcode documentation it says you can either display an image or text. I would like to display both images, charts, labels and maybe even some buttons. Will the UISegmentController not support this?

Comment: Charts and buttons inside your UISegmentController buttons sound strange ;) It would be helpful if you got your image link working to show what you mean.

Comment: Basically the buttons will work as a form of filter, showing graphics/information only relevant for the chosen category. I've now updated the image. Hopefully it works now.

Comment: Looks good! Functionally, UISegmentedControl is what you want but if the categories don’t change I’d probably just go with UIButtons, easier to customize the look of.